# Ruby on Rails: Access information from other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Another newbie Ruby on Rails question:

In my post view, I want to show the authors name. The post database table stores the authors id which is the same as the users id column in the users table. The user also has a username column in the user table.

So having the users id, how do I get the users name?

Comment: .. and I find myself back here through google over a year later. awesome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
User.find(user_id).username
```

is one way.

If you were to have a [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) relationship between post and user it would be

```
post.user.username
```

which is much more 'the Rails way'.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I expect >.<. This is ok to use in a view?

Comment: The second one definitely is. The first one less so.

Comment: Hmm I have "belongs_to :user" in my post model but post.user.login does not work

Answer (score 3):

In your Post model, you should have:

```
belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'
```

Then from your view, you can access the username with @post.author.username

Comment: Thanks. I am getting "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.login" though

Comment: You may need to add a :foreign_key => 'authors_id' (or whatever your column name is) if it's not predictable by rails.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the id of the author of a post, you should be able to pass that to the find method on your user class. something like this "User.find(post.author_id)" would yield a user object that you could get the username of.